# Shutting down mysql from command line [Windows][DOS]

Tags: mysql, windows, macos, dos, mysqladmin

I want to shutdown mysql server from command line.

If I use `taskkill.exe` or forcefully, it stops the mysql server but when I start mysql again. It shows

```
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.13 started; log sequence number 1600927
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2013-08-31 16:00:35 3940 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
```

Recovery actually takes time to start the server. And also sometimes it gets failed to start, if the database is extremely large.

So I want to shutdown normally like:

`mysqladmin -u root -pmysql shutdown`

Above command works but **MySQL Root Password may change** so I want a **similar command of Mac OS X** below for **Windows**:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p$(cat /path/to/mysql/root/password) shutdown
```

Basically I want to read the password from file. Is it possible in DOS ?

Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Here is the command

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('type path\to\mysql\root\password.txt') do @(mysqladmin -u root -p%f shutdown)
```